# I am doing the Kotlin android basics course and I'm getting expecting member declaration on a simple line of code, I have no idea what to do

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi I'm new to kotlin and I'm working on the words dictionary app I accidentally deleted a line of code but managed to put it back in and now for some reason it's not working. The error is expecting member declaration. I'm guessing it's linked to line 118 of the code expecting top level declaration, it's just a curly bracket. PLease help

```
/**
 * Adapter for the [RecyclerView] in [DetailActivity].
 */
class WordAdapter(private val letterId: String, context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<WordAdapter.WordViewHolder>() {

    private val filteredWords: List<String>

    init {
        // Retrieve the list of words from res/values/arrays.xml
        val words = context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.words).toList()

        filteredWords = words
            // Returns items in a collection if the conditional clause is true,
            // in this case if an item starts with the given letter,
            // ignoring UPPERCASE or lowercase.
            .filter { it.startsWith(letterId, ignoreCase = true) }
            // Returns a collection that it has shuffled in place
            .shuffled()
            // Returns the first n items as a [List]
            .take(5)
            // Returns a sorted version of that [List]
            .sorted()
    }

    class WordViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val button = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_item)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = filteredWords.size

    /**
     * Creates new views with R.layout.item_view as its template
     */
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): WordViewHolder {
        val layout = LayoutInflater
            .from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false)

        // Setup custom accessibility delegate to set the text read
        layout.accessibilityDelegate = Accessibility

        return WordViewHolder(layout)
    }

    /**
     * Replaces the content of an existing view with new data
     */
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: WordViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.button.setOnClickListener {
            val queryUrl: Uri = **Uri.parse("${DetailActivity.SEARCH_PREFIX}${item}")<---Unresolved reference item**
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, queryUrl)
            **context.startActivity(intent)<---Unresolved reference context**

        }


    }
        val item = filteredWords[position]<--Unresolved reference position
        // Needed to call startActivity
        val context = holder.view.context <--Unresolved reference holder

        // Set the text of the WordViewHolder
        **holder.button.text = item**  **<---This line is the error Expecting member declaration**

    }
    // Setup custom accessibility delegate to set the text read with
    // an accessibility service
    companion object Accessibility : View.AccessibilityDelegate() {
        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(
            host: View?,
            info: AccessibilityNodeInfo?
        ) {
            super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
            // With `null` as the second argument to [AccessibilityAction], the
            // accessibility service announces "double tap to activate".
            // If a custom string is provided,
            // it announces "double tap to <custom string>".
            val customString = host?.context?.getString(R.string.look_up_word)
            val customClick =
                AccessibilityNodeInfo.AccessibilityAction(
                    AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK,
                    customString
                )
            info?.addAction(customClick)
        }
    }
}          <------Here is line 118 Expecting a top level declaration
```

Comment: please update your post to include enough information for us to recreate the entire problem, we have no idea where this code is going, probably a good idea to post the file as is, in this case

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have exported a .kt file can I attach it to the post

Comment: Can you state in the question which line is line 118? We do not see line numbers in the code here.

Comment: highlighted line 118 and 93 the two lines causing the problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete the '}' from top of val item declaration

Comment: Thanks, this worked but I have two more errors line 82 and 80 I will highlight them in the code

Comment: val item and val context must be above your clicklistener declaration, just cut them and paste them above.

Comment: OK now I'm getting Expecting member declaration for the line beginning with CONTEXT

Comment: val item = filteredWords[position]

        val context = holder.view.context

        holder.button.setOnClickListener {
            val queryUrl: Uri = Uri.parse("${DetailActivity.SEARCH_PREFIX}${item}")
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, queryUrl)
            context.startActivity(intent)

        }

Comment: val context = holder.view.context **holder**.button.setOnClickListener { <---Expecting an element holder

Comment: val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, queryUrl) **context**.startActivity(intent) } <--Expecting an element

Comment: press enter for inserting new line after holder.view.context

Comment: in kotlin language you have to add new line before new code lines because kotlin does not use ';'

Comment: original problem occurrs expecting member declaration holder.button.text = item

Comment: (holder.button as Button).text = item